# How do I use i18next handling a large number of translated files

Tags: i18next

We have about 1000+ copywriting in our project and it is too tiring to create keys manually. How do I automatically generate these unique keys and inject them into the code? Just like react-intl

Answer (score 1):

You can use the localization as a service offered by locize.com

https://www.i18next.com/#localization-as-a-service

Comment: My system does not provide external access for security reasons, so I cannot use it